# Оптимизация приложения под разные экраны (drawable)

Tags: android, xml, android-drawable, android-xml

Сразу извиняюсь за вопрос т.к. тема давно не новая, но всё же. Как подготовить drawable для разных экранов? Ведь диагональ может быть разной, а плотность пикселей одна и та же. И те рисунки что на экране 4.7-5 дюймов кажутся нормальными на экранах 7+ совсем мелкие. И еще вопрос можно ли квалификаторы указывать так (drawable-xlarge-xhdpi)?? Заранее спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для начальной подготовки drawable я бы посоветовал использовать ImageAsset в самой студии, это облегчит генерацию и вы увидите разницу на разных устройствах.

```
drawable-xlarge-xhdpi
```

Так можно использовать, так как это разные квалификаторы. Первый - отвечает за размер/диагональ экрана, второй - за плотность.

*Тема, очень хорошо описана во многих источниках, а лучше сразу оф доки читать, там очень хорошо всё разъясняется.* 
https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: Спасибо) Буду пробывать

Answer (score 1):

К сожалению, на всех устройствах `Android` не только диагональ экрана разная, но и его плотность.

Для удобной работы с этим "зоопарком" размеров и плотностей в `Google` разработали квалификаторы к ресурсным папкам. Почитать об этом Вы можете здесь - [открыть ссылку на сайт Developer Android](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html?hl=ru)

Для примера оставлю здесь кусок информации из статьи выше

Плотность пикселов на экране (dpi):

- ldpi
- mdpi
- hdpi
- xhdpi
- xxhdpi
- xxxhdpi
- nodpi
- tvdpi

Это означает, что Вы можете создать в свое директории `/res` следующие `drawable` поддиректории:

- drawable-ldpi
- drawable-mdpi
- drawable-hdpi
- drawable-xhdpi
- drawable-xxhdpi
- drawable-xxxhdpi
- drawable-nodpi
- drawable-tvdpi

Для чего каждая из директорий `drawable` ? Ответ на этот вопрос в расширенной статье по ссылке выше.

**upd0**

[Поддержка различных экранов - ENG](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

А так же, думаю, будет полезно **прочесть** эту статью - [статья на fandroid.info](http://www.fandroid.info/podderzhka-raznyh-razreshenij-ekrana-v-android-prilozheniyah/)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ) Но я пока всё равно не понимаю как быть с разными drawable? Потому как допустим устройство 5.0 дюймов xhdpi  и 10 дюймов тоже xhdpi и все они берут ресурсы из папки drawable-xhdpi, правильно?

Comment: @Serhiy все зависит от плотности, а не от диагонали. Плотность (dpi) - количество точек на дюйм, и ее значение закладывает производитель устройства. Чем выше плотность, тем больше будет "x" в квалификаторе.